# CordovaのJSはloader.js？

Tags: cordova

初歩的な質問ですみません。
cordovaのjsを使用したいときには、componentsのloader.jsを利用すればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

`cordova create`により生成したcordovaプロジェクトでは、cordova.jsは自動的に読み込まれるようになっていますので、index.htmlに直接記述したりloader.jsを利用してcordova.jsを読み込む必要はありません。

cordovaで提供されているAPIの利用が可能になると`deviceready`イベントがトリガされますので、以下のように`deviceready`にコールバック関数を渡せば、cordovaAPIが利用可能な状態になったかどうか把握できます。

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  // ここでCordovaAPIが利用可能になります。
}, false);
```

cordova以外のライブラリ（jQueryなど）を利用するには、index.htmlにスクリプトタグを記述します。

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js">
```

jQueryの`ready`とCordovaの`deviceready`では、jQueryのほうが、準備ができた後にイベントを呼び出しても適切に処理してくれますので`deviceready`を先に受け取るようにしたほうが良いようです。

プロジェクトの規模が大きくなると、ライブラリの読み込み順位によってプログラムが動かなくなってしまったりすることがありますので、require.jsを利用する方法も検討してみると良いでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

Cordovaを使用する際に指定するJavaScriptは `cordova.js` です。Cordovaをラップしたフレームワーク等を使用している場合はこの限りではないかもしれませんが、例えばIonicでは少なくとも `cordova.js`を呼び出して使用します。
(呼び出し例としては `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` のように記載します。)

この `cordova.js`はjQueryなどのように自身で直接ダウンロードして配置するタイプのものではなく、 `cordova platform add android` のように対応のプラットフォームを追加後、 `cordova build android` のようにビルドを実行した際に、当該プラットフォームのフォルダ内に自動で生成されるものです。
Androidの例で言えば、 `$アプリフォルダ/platforms/android/platform_www` 以下に生成されるはずです。